# Wordpress write-access when using Docker for Windows

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I want to setup a local Wordpress dev environment, so I'm trying out Docker for Windows and WSL. I've used standard images (wordpress:4.9.7, mysql:5.7 and phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin) and use docker-compose. I can get Wordpress running, but run into problems when I try to update or add plugins.

I have this in the Wordpress service section of the docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

This means that:

1. I can edit theme and plugin files in the host (great), however...
2. the container's /var/www/html/wp-content folder is root:root 755. So Wordpress can't update/add plugins or upload other files from the admin - and I can't chown or chmod this.

If I remove the volumes from docker-compose.yml I get write access back but I can't edit or persist the wp-content file from the host.

I just want an easy Wordpress dev environment. **Is there a way to get this working with Docker for Windows, or will I have to go back to using a virtual machine?**

**EDIT: According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#volumes) it's not possible to host mount a volume with Docker for Windows and have anything but 755 permissions.**

It doesn't specify whether the owner of the mounted volume within the container can be changed from root:root or not. I've tried various ways to do this within the running container (*chown appears to fail silently*), as well as trying various "user:..." additions to the docker-compose.yml but without success. If the owner of a shared volume cannot be set or modified then Wordpress cannot write to that shared volume.

One possible solution might be to use the mounted volume during development (i.e. when writing code in Sublime on the host in Windows), and then remove the mount whenever I need to give Wordpress write permissions (e.g. updating plugins or adding media - basically whenever it actually needs to run). Sounds pretty horrible, but seems like I have limited options.

Still would love a good Windows workflow if anyone has any other suggestions. My hope is that there is a way to change the owner of the mounted volume within the container. I haven't found anything saying definitively that this is or is not possible, so would love some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options in here:

1. Start the container as root using `user: root` inside the compose file.
2. Build your own Docker image that simply extends wordpress using `FROM wordpress`
   and `RUN chmod -R 766 /var/www/html/wp-content`
3. Manually go into the current running container using `docker exec --user root -it <container> bash` and run `chmod -R 766 /var/www/html/wp-content`.

Comment: I've tried method's 1 and 3 and they don't work for me. For method 1, it runs as root by default anyway (I've checked by entering the container and running whoami), but regardless I've tried and still Wordpress can't write and chmod doesn't have any effect on the wp-content folder. For method 3, again there is no effect on that wp-content folder if I run chmod. I think the permissions are "locked" when the volume is shared which is the whole problem.

Comment: @Ben - did you ever get any closer to a viable solution to this problem? I'm struggling with the same issue now after switching from Linux to Windows 10. Any help or hints would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.